# Addition of two numbers in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am trying to add two numbers in MVC.

My requirement is "I have 2 text boxes in View from which I have to retrieve data to controller"

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Addition", "Addition", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="Text1" type="text" value=@ViewBag.a name="firstNum" />
    <input id="Text2" type="text" value=@ViewBag.b name="secondNum" />
    <input id="Text3" type="text" value=@ViewBag.result />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller Name : Addition
Action Name: Addition

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Addition(FormCollection fc)
        {
            string[] keyss = fc.AllKeys;
            ViewBag.a = fc.Keys[0];
            ViewBag.b = fc.Keys[1];
            ViewBag.total = ViewBag.a + ViewBag.b;
            return View();
        }
```

Now, from this form collection I want to retrieve values of textboxes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the powers of MVC is the model binder - which you are completely ignoring here. Create a view model to match the expected content of your view

```
public class AdditionViewModel
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Use this as the expected parameter in your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addition(AdditionViewModel model)
{
    model.Result = model.A + model.B;
    return View(model);
}
```

Then finally in your view

```
@model AdditionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Addition", "Addition", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.A)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.B)
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Result)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Using Model Binder is good way of programming and I already knew using it James. I was just trying to think differently ;) 
Thanks for you Answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the data in to ur controller , afterwards you just add Addition view and use 
   `@ViewBag.total` simple or you also can use viewdata or tempdata in case if u required .

Answer (score 0):

The better way is

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Addition(int firstNum, int secondNum )
  {
   ViewBag.Result=firstNum+secondNum;
   return View();

  }
```

Make sure you are doing a Numeric validation at client side